# How to access an item in an asana collection by index

Tags: ruby, asana

I'm trying to update code for importing trello cards to asana, and I had to update to the latest asana gem https://github.com/Asana/ruby-asana.

Now I'm getting this error when I'm trying to access a collection item by index.

```
exportTrelloToAsana.rb:63:in `block in <main>': undefined method `[]' for #<Asana::Resources::Collection:0x007fbba1d0d810> (NoMethodError)
    from exportTrelloToAsana.rb:56:in `each'
    from exportTrelloToAsana.rb:56:in `<main>'
```

What is the correct syntax for accessing a Asana::Resources::Collection by index?

```
client = Asana::Client.new do |c|
  c.authentication :access_token, PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN
end

workspaces = client.workspaces.find_all
workspace = workspaces[0]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned in the [README.md](https://github.com/Asana/ruby-asana/blob/master/README.md) the library will return a [Asana::Resources::Collection](https://github.com/Asana/ruby-asana/blob/master/lib/asana/resource_includes/collection.rb) for API responses containing multiple elements and/or multiple pages.

Among other things the collection is an [Enumerable](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html) and will expose the Enumerable API.

There are several ways to iterate through the elements of the collection or to grab specific elements of the collection:

```
workspaces = client.workspaces.find_all
workspaces.take(1)
#<Asana::Workspace id: 1234, name: "Moon Landing">

workspaces.first    
#<Asana::Workspace id: 1234, name: "Moon Landing">

workspaces.each
#<Enumerator:0x000001032df790>
```

There are also several [examples](https://github.com/Asana/ruby-asana/tree/master/examples) including one using the personal access token to [iterate over the workspaces available](https://github.com/Asana/ruby-asana/blob/master/examples/personal_access_token.rb)